# VB.Net System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException Read-Only DB object

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, excel

I am currently working on a VB app that reads a new excel sheet daily from a network folder and copies data to database. I am stuck on an error when trying to first use the fill() method of my dataAdapter. The error is "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E09): Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only."
Here is a snippet of code where the error occurs (last line):

```
        Dim dt2 As DataTable
        Dim myAdapter2 As Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        dt2 = New DataTable()
        myAdapter2 = New Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(xls_sql, My.Settings.xlsfile)
        myAdapter2.Fill(dt2)
```

My query is basic:

```
xls_sql = "SELECT * FROM [" & FN & "]"
```

and here is my connection string setting:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\temp\;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT = Delimited'
```

A coworker suggested I change the properties to

```
="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

Comment: _"`A coworker suggested... to use IMEX=1"_ have you tried that? If yes and it worked there's no question, if not, mention it. If you haven't tried it, try it.

Comment: Oh ddang sorry, didn't type enough. I did try it and it gave same error

Comment: Your file is on the network. And the directory in which it sits may have no full access rights from the user account that runs code. Or file itself is read-only

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Had to edit registry key for Microsoft Jet Engine, as it currently only accepted a select few file types - not including .xls.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245407#/en-us/kb/245407